# XML array with 2 href attributes

Tags: php

I have the following XML array:

```
["link"]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#311 (1) {
              ["@attributes"]=>
              array(3) {
                ["type"]=>
                string(9) "text/html"
                ["href"]=>
                string(48) "http://twitter.com/bob/statuses/1226112723"
                ["rel"]=>
                string(9) "alternate"
              }
            }
            [1]=>
            object(SimpleXMLElement)#312 (1) {
              ["@attributes"]=>
              array(3) {
                ["type"]=>
                string(9) "image/png"
                ["href"]=>
                string(59) "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/226895523/Dan_normal.png"
                ["rel"]=>
                string(5) "image"
              }
            }
          }
```

It's inside a bigger array, I need to get the first and second hef attribute seperatly so that I can put one href as a `<a>` link and another with a `<img>`.

How can I output each href rather than both together?

Currently trying this:

```
 foreach($entry->link as $link) {
     echo $link->attributes()->href;
 }
```

Comment: What is the output you get from the ECHO in the loop you showed? Can you paste some more code because it is not clear what loops you currently have. Thanks.

Comment: I get a string like: http://twitter.com/bob/statuses/1226112723http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/226895523/Dan_normal.png concatonated together

Comment: Would be easier if you posted the output from `$xml->asxml()` instead of `var_dump($xml);`. Or just say that you're parsing the feed from http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/bob.atom via simplexml (because that's what you're doing, isn't it?)

Comment: Yes it is, I just want to post everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/bob.atom';
$feed = simplexml_load_file($url);

$testStop = 0;
foreach($feed->entry as $entry) {
  echo 'title: ', $entry->title, "\n";

  // store all link/@href in a hashtable
  // so you can access them in any order you like
  // without resorting to xpath or alike.
  $links = array();
  foreach($entry->link as $link) {
    $links[(string)$link['rel']] = (string)$link['href'];
  }

  if ( isset($links['image']) ) {
    echo '<img src="', $links['image'], '" />', "\n";
  }
  if ( isset($links['alternate']) ) {
    echo '<a href="', $links['alternate'], '" />alternate</a>', "\n";
  }
  echo "----\n";
  if ( 2 < ++$testStop ) die;
}
```

(currently) prints

```
title: kolchak: Sometimes I think I need a new butler. But then it's like "Nah, he's still got one thumb. We good."
<img src="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/668496250/Picture_14_normal.jpg" />
<a href="http://twitter.com/kolchak/statuses/10648055680" />alternate</a>
----
title: shitmydadsays: "War hero? No. I was a doc in Vietnam. My job was to say "This is what happens when ."
<img src="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/362705903/dad_normal.jpg" />
<a href="http://twitter.com/shitmydadsays/statuses/10580558323" />alternate</a>
----
title: shitmydadsays: "I lost 20 pounds...How? I drank bear piss and took up fencing. How the you think, son? I exercised."
<img src="http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/362705903/dad_normal.jpg" />
<a href="http://twitter.com/shitmydadsays/statuses/10084782056" />alternate</a>
----
```

But you might also be interested in [xsl(t)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `href` attributes using normal array/object access. Just store them in an array for later use:

```
$hrefs = array();

foreach($array['links'] as $links) {
    foreach($links->attributes as $key>=$value) {
        if('href' == $key) {
            $hrefs[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

// $href[0] = "http://twitter.com/bob/statuses/1226112723"
// $href[1] = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/226895523/Dan_normal.png"
```

This makes use of `SimpleXMLElement`'s [`attributes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method.

I don't think that you can access the attributes directly ($elment->@attributes) as this is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First href - $xml['link'][0]->attributes()->href

Second href - $xml['link'][1]->attributes()->href